# Adding a new Column to Table Structure with a command in Phpmyadmin with Defined Value

Tags: mysql

Basically I need to add a new column to a table. I need to call that column category and in that column of Category I want the default value to be the name of that new category column I will add.

How can I do this inside of phpmyadmin by command?

I have about 100 tables and each table has 100+ items, which is why I need to do it with a command rather than manually adding the column and the name.

Thanks

Comment: In order to insert a new default value, you need to update each row, so in this case better way to alter table with new column and update each table row by row.

Comment: Ok. So the inserting of column value must be done manually for each row? Can't be done when I Insert new column?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco   updating each table row by row is better in 100 tables of 100+ items each?

Comment: Try to add column with `NOT NULL` and set `DEFAULT` value, on test table, see how it works, I'm not sure if it's add a default value to existing row right away.

Comment: I'm stupid, looks like there was an, "as defined:" option under default value, which worked. Thanks, sorry.

Comment: Yep it does works, `alter table test.Name add NewCol varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'new val'` it add new values to existing ones too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add new column in a exsisting table with default value:-

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD new_col_name VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'new value' NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alter table test.Name add NewCol varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'new val'
```

It should helps.